# How long does a chat message stay in history?

Tags: support, badges, chat

I was wondering about the **Outspoken Badge**:

> Posted 10 messages in chat that were starred by 10 different users

I am not sure how long those messages stay in place.

I know that each one of the 10 is independent from each other, but I think that the question is how much time there is to get 10 people to star a chat comment.

Comment: I think they stay forever, unless the chat room is deleted.

Answer (score 8):

> but I am not sure how long those this message stay in place.

Chat messages do not get deleted; all old messages can be found on the transcript of a room (scroll up and click on the "full transcript" button).

If a room gets deleted, the messages do not really get deleted; they are only visible to users with 10k reputation or more, and moderators.

Comment: While messages aren't deleted, stars can be removed.  For example, the Python room unstars messages that don't get 3 stars in 3 days.  So depending on when/how SE calculates the badge progress, counts might change.